# Scanning and Parsing HTML with regex

Tags: html, regex

I have a specific HTML source file that I need to be able to scan and parse and I am having trouble. While I understand that HTML aren't supposed to be part, this is part of the assignment, so I do not have any choice.

So far the regex I have are,

`<[^/!].*?>` for start tags

I have other regex for end tag and comment which works fine, but I cannot seem to type them here.

I am trouble coming up with a regex to detect all texts in between tags or of the body.

I would greatly appreciate any help possible.

Comment: Your requirement is unclear, but in any case regex isn't the best choice for your problem, especially if you expect to have nested HTML tags.  Instead, look into using an HTML _parser_.

Comment: Relevant—https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: This is exactly what a **parser** was made for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: show your html too

Comment: <LI> The printout you submit should include answers to the above questions
and the console transcript of running the default
ant build, which will apply your grammar to the three input files.
<LI> Be sure to commit and push your code, as we will be looking at
it as well as the printout.

Comment: Above is part of the html I need to scan and parse, basically I am having trouble using regex to detect content other than the tags.

Comment: The printout you submit should include answers to the above questions and the console transcript of running the default ant build, which will apply your grammar to the three input files.  (I need to be able to detect this)

Comment: try this one <LI>(.*?)<LI>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this

```
/<LI>(.*?)<LI>/g
```

1) `<LI>`matches the characters`<LI>` literally (case sensitive)

2) `.*?` matches any character (except for line terminators)

3) `*?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times 
      as possible, expanding as needed

4) `<LI>`matches the characters`<LI>` literally (case sensitive)

5) `g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)

Comment: Have you considered what it will do with `<LI><STRONG>Here's an <A href="http://www.example.com/">Example</A></STRONG></LI>`? Is that a desirable/acceptable outcome?